# Java Sound input on OS X. Volume control not supported? Crashes

Tags: java, macos, audio

For both the built-in mic and built-in input on my MacBook Pro, the following lines both return `false`:

```
line.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
line.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
```

the `line` is an instance of `TargetDataLine` and has been successfully `open()`'d.

Because I can't set the gain, any audio I capture is at an extremely low level and is swamped by noise. The JVM (1.6.0_24, com.apple.javajdk16.cmd, OS X 10.6.7) also frequently crashes when calling `TargetDataLine.close()`.

Anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this - here are OS X java sound demo-apps.
http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/samples/JavaSoundDemo/

Have a working os x gain control too.

Based on comments:

Check this too: http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#recording_volume , but honestly never tried it. At the page:

> The obvious solution would be to get a
>   Control object of type VOLUME or
>   MASTER_GAIN for the TargetDataLine and
>   manipulate the volume via this object.
>   However, this is not possible, since
>   no known Java Sound implementation
>   supports any controls for
>   TargetDataLine instances.
>
> What you can do is to use the system
>   mixer to control the recording volume
>   --- it affects hardware settings in the soundcard. One possibility is to
>   use the mixer application of the
>   operating system. The other
>   possibility is using Port lines from
>   inside a Java Sound application. See
>   the section Ports for details.

Comment: I tried that. It only has gain control for playback. Any recorded audio is at a very low level.

Comment: New link for sound demo: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html